# Multi-level sorting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have to run a report that has the data shown in the pictures. I need to sort it only by the R-A** (release) in column c then sort each release by assembly (column b).  I can't sort it that way though because of the weight in column c. Is there any way to sort it so it is like the "correctly sorted" picture? I thought about trying to use a macro but unfortunately the quantity of assemblies put release varies so that wouldn't work. I know only slightly more than the basic excel user but I can follow directions really well!

[Correctly Sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk5ts.png)

[Sorted by column c then b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL2a2.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information about "the weight in column c"? I can not understand why "115D R-A1 4698#" is ahead of "115D R-A1 4692#". Thx~

Comment: Sure, it's the weight of the assembly in lbs. So it's 4,698 lbs. It's the order it has to be in unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-level sorting is accomplished with this ribbon item: [image]

Just click on add level, and the up/down arrow to change the order

[image]

Comment: I tried that and that's what it ends up looking like in the first picture because it sorts the weight at the end (4698#) too. I need a way for it to ignore the weight and sort only by the sequence then the assembly.

Comment: sorry, I must have missed the weight part. Anyway, sounds like you need a helper column  (with a formula similar to `=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)`)that takes out the weight thing and sort by that column instead of the orginal

Answer (score 0):

@Stacy
Thanks for your explaination, I found that I misread the contents of column B cells.

But based on my tests, if you want to get the sort as "Correctly Sorted", you can try sorting column B first, then column C, and finally column A.

[image]